# How to receive exception in c# dll and pass it up to a c++ program?

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll

The c# dll's functions are all accessible by the c++ program. One of my functions throws an exception that isn't showing in the terminal when the c++ program is run.

**Structure of the C# DLL**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Ace {

  [ComVisible(true)]
  public interface IAce1{

    int getTheValue();


  }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Acer : IAce1
    {
        public int getTheValue()
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error recognized", new ArithmeticExpression("Bey");
        }

}
```

**C++ Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tchar.h"

#import {I linked the .tlb file here} no_namespace

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IAce1 object(__uuidof(Acer));

    try {
        printf("error: %d", object->getTheValue());
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        std::cout << e.Description() << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.Error() << std::endl;
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
```

Nothing is returned from the catch block. How can I get the exception to bubble up?

Comment: I stopped using COM as interop. You should write an interop layer in C++/CLI. That forwards the call from C++ to .Net, then catches any .Net exceptions and throws new C++ exceptions. Introduction to C++/CLI : [C++/CLI in ten minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes). And [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)